# Remotely manage IIS on NANO 2016 using IIS Manager

Tags: iis, nano-server, remote-administration

Is it possible to remotely manage an IIS server, running on Server 2016 NANO using the IIS Manager 10 from the client?

I have a newly created nano VM. I've installed IIS, dotnet, IIS Administration API, and File Services on it. IIS is working from the client side. I can see the default page when I browse to the VM's IP address. I can authenticate to the IIS Administration API through the browser. I can copy files from the client machine to the server's inetpub\wwwroot directory through Windows Explorer. Everything seems to be working but when I open IIS Manager 10 on my client machine and try to connect it to the nano server, I get an error message that says "Could not connect to the specified computer. Details: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

I've already followed the instructions at 
https://blogs.iis.net/adminapi/microsoft-iis-administration-on-nano-server
That's how I've gotten as far as I have but now I'm just stuck and can't seem to find any path forward.

EDIT: BTW, I am able to connect to the site and administer it with http://manage.iis.net/

Comment: What you discovered is the answer. Nano servers are supposed to be managed via PowerShell or the web portal. IIS Manager becomes the past.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it's not possible.

You can see what's available with `dism /online /get-feature`, but `IIS-WebServerManagementTools` is not in that list.